# how to find percentile for one value with array of percentiles

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, percentile

I have one value 3.1547 and CI = [60,70,80,90.5] this is another array.
I have to find Percentile for 3.1547 from each array value, like I need 60th percentile for 3.1547 and 70th percentile for 3.1547 and 80th percentile for 3.1547 and so on.

Comment: Please explain your idea in detail.

Comment: I have to find 60th,70th,80th,90.5th percentile for one value 3.1547 problem is those percentile values are in array..

Comment: What is the 60th percentile of 3.1547 in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```
CI = [60,70,80,90.5]
pi=3.1547
for value,data in enumerate(CI): #== The enumerate() method adds counter to an iterable and returns it (the enumerate object).
    CI[value]=(data/100)*(pi)
print(CI)
```

Output:

```
[1.89282, 2.20829, 2.5237600000000002, 2.8550035]
```

If you want to round the output:

```
CI[value]=round((data/100)*(pi),2) #== Insert any number after the comma (like 2,3)
```